# Which expansions should not be used together in Carcassonne?

Tags: carcassonne

I have really been into Carcassonne lately and have purchased many expansions, even though I'm still missing some of the rarer ones. I have the following:

- Base Game
- Expansion 1: Inns and Cathedrals
- Expansion 2: Traders and Builders
- Expansion 3: Princess and the Dragon
- Expansion 4: The Tower
- Expansion 5: Abbey & Mayor
- Expansion 6: Count, King & Robber
- Expansion 8: Bridges, Castles & Bazaars
- All 6 mini expansions

I have since realized that many expansions have rulings that contradict and/or cause ambiguous situations together and that some just cannot be played at the same time. Are there expansions that should just not be played or are there known combinations of expansions that are the ideal game? I'm looking to have the most fun possible without having arguments over how the expansions work together.

Edit: Here is an example of problems that can occur with some expansions. This is a question I posted a few days ago: [Carcassonne interaction between "The Robbers" and "The Messages"](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/32136/carcassonne-interaction-between-the-robbers-and-the-messages)

Thanks
L-P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made games with this expansions.

Base Game, Inns and Cathedrals, Traders and Builders, Princess and the Dragon, The Tower, Abbey & Mayor, Count, King & Robber; Bridges, Castles & Bazaars and wheel of fortune.

And all worked fine together, the most important are: 1. the game can have 4 or 5 hours long and 2. beware when the fields with barn are unexpectedly joined under some bridge.